# How to get property of object in lookup field?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

When I select some Contact in a lookup field, I want to get his nickname (for example). How to do this using Javascript?

I already have GUID of that Contact.

Edit:
On Case entity I have lookup field with Contact type.
Every entity is default. Now, when I choose some contact on Case entity, how can I get Contact's Nickname?

Comment: can you put some more detail i.e. what is in the contact field. Generally this isn't clear and I don't think it's answerable in it's current format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for REST endpoints to go ask CRM for the Contact's Nickname via javascript. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223650/crm-2011-setting-a-default-value-with-jscript) has an answer by Anwar which explains how to use the REST endpoints to get data. In your case, notice how he is requesting the conact:

```
odataUri = odataUri + '/ContactSet?$select=ContactId,FullName&$filter=
```

you could get the nickname in a similar fashion:

```
odataUri = odataUri + '/ContactSet?$select=ContactId,NickName&$filter=
```